# function openDialog() set width and set height Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to set the width of a [dialog in a Google Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXskO.png).

So far my code is:

```
// Use this code for Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets.
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Cadastro')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will set your height and width.

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setHeight(100)
  .setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title')
  }//`enter code here`
```

Of course you also need to add a index.html file to the script editor like:

```
Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

Comment: If that worked for you, could you please approve the answer? Thanks.